# Form Submission Bug

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have created a basic CRM.

I have contacts in which I attach tasks and trails (group of tasks) to.

The way the trails are assigned is by having pre-defined trails in a 'trail' table in my db.

```
'id' 'category' 'set_name' 'function' 'text' 'days'
```

a few example entries:

```
'1' 'Follow up' '2 Weeks' 'Call' 'Call them to say hello' '7'
'1' 'Follow up' '2 Weeks' 'SMS' 'Thank you for the chat yesterday' '8'
'1' 'Prospecting' '1 Week' 'SMS' Thank you for the chat' '0'
```

A user would select a trail in a drop down menu in a web form. This is the code for the option:

```
<select name="activity_schedule_2" class="insert_new_select hovering">
    <option value="notrail">No Trail</option>
    <?php
        $set_get = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT category,set_name FROM trail ORDER BY category");
        if ($set_get->num_rows != 0){
            while($set_1 = $set_get->fetch_assoc()) {
                $set_category = $set_1['category'];
                $set_name = $set_1['set_name'];      
    ?>
    <OPTION VALUE="<?php echo $set_category.','.$set_name; ?>"><?php echo $set_category.' :: '.$set_name ?></OPTION>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

On the php page that this form submits to I utilise the following code:

```
$contact_activityschedule = $_POST['activity_schedule_2'];
    $contact_activityschedule = explode(",", $contact_activityschedule);
        $contact_activityschedule_1 = $contact_activityschedule[0];
        $contact_activityschedule_2 = $contact_activityschedule[1];
```

What I am doing here is separating the 'category' & the 'set_name'. Preparing to query them both.

Below is the code to submit this section of the form:

```
if ($contact_activityschedule != 'notrail'){
    $setname = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM trail WHERE category = '$contact_activityschedule_1' AND set_name = '$contact_activityschedule_2'");
        if($setname->num_rows != ''){
            while($set_this = $setname->fetch_assoc()){
                $set_id = $set_this['id'];
                $set_category = $set_this['category'];
                $set_name = $set_this['set_name'];
                $set_function = $set_this['function'];
                $set_text = $set_this['text'];
                $set_days = $set_this['days'];

                //Due date = today + 'days'             
                $dueDate = date('Y:m:d', strtotime('+'.$set_days.' days'));

                $taskentry = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO task (datetime, template, function, name, text, attachment, time_begin, time_due, property_id) VALUES (NOW(), '', '$set_function', '$set_name', '$set_text', '', '', '$dueDate', '')");

                    $get_task_id = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();");
                        if($get_task_id->num_rows != ''){
                            while($thetaskid = $get_task_id->fetch_assoc()){
                                $final_task_id = $thetaskid['id'];  

                                $linkentry = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO link (datetime, user_id, current, contact_id, contact_id_b, property_id, group_id, task_id, theme_id, relationship, relationship_alias) VALUES (NOW(), '1', '1', '$final_contact_id', '', '$final_property_id', '', '$final_task_id', '', '', '')");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see I have designed the code to search for all rows with the 'trail' table, with the matching 'category' and 'set_name' and submit them into the 'task' table (I also have a 'link' table that I use to connect the contact to the task).

The bug I am receiving is extremely strange. If, for example, there is 5 tasks in a particular trail. It will only enter 4 of them. If it's a set of two it will typically enter both of them.

I have scrapped through the database assuming the error is coming from a miss type in the 'category' or 'set_names' but they are all identical. The bug has no pattern it just randomly skips certain rows.

Comment: Use `mysqli_error` after execution of each query. One of them is probably failing as you don't seem to escape your data.

Comment: @Jocelyn Thank you for the advice. I will look into what all of this means. I don't know what you mean by escaping data, yet the way you say it makes it seem like something very basic I should be doing. I will find the documentation for mysqli_error and look into that too.

Comment: Read more here: [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @Jocelyn Hello! You were correct. Because I wasn't escaping the strings it was causing an error from the special characters. As soon as I user mysqli escape string on all input fields it fixed all errors. I don't know the etiquette of this site but you basically answered my question. So can you submit it as an answer so I can accept yours?